# The effect of dietary protein on neurodegeneration

Tags: neurology, proteins, cognitive-science, alzheimers, neurodegenerative-disease

I have recently come across the following two studies:

- [The first paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3982836/) was performed on an Alzheimer's disease mouse model, and found that protein restriction cycles reduce IGF-1 and phosphorylated Tau, the latter of which is a commonly observed biomarker related to neurodegenerative diseases. It was also found that mice that had protein restriction cycles had improved cognition, among other findings.
- [The second one](https://content.iospress.com/articles/journal-of-alzheimers-disease/jad170742) was performed on cognitively normal adults, and found a decreased burden of brain beta-amyloid, which is also a biomarker that is usually correlated with cognitive decline.

While I understand that none of these studies attempt to suggest that either dietary protein consumption habit is better for humans, they seem to contradict themselves a bit. Though different biomarkers were observed, they both came to a different conclusion regarding cognitive function, albeit with obviously different experimental conditions as well.

These results got me asking the following question: what does the current literature suggest is better for humans regarding retaining or improving cognitive function, as it pertains to dietary protein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't enough research to say more or less dietary protein is "better" for Alzheimer's in the long-term ([Review Article - Protein and Alzheimer's](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6627761/)).

In the short-term, Alzheimer's occurs mostly in older adults, who are at risk of muscle degradation with insufficient protein intake. Muscle degradation dramatically increases the risks of fall and generally decreases quality of life ([Review Article - Sarcopenia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4269139/)); for the elderly, then, the benefits of consuming more protein would probably outweigh any slightly increased risk of Alzheimer's. Again, it isn't clear whether protein consumption plays a significant role either way ([Review Article - Protein and Alzheimer's](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6627761/)).

Most evidence regarding diet and long-term Alzheimer's risk says that eating a healthy diet (lots of vegetables, not so much red meat, etc.) is beneficial ([National Institute on Aging](https://www.nia.nih.gov/health/what-do-we-know-about-diet-and-prevention-alzheimers-disease)). As with most diseases, the cumulative effect of a healthy diet is probably more important than any single aspect.